# android uses-feature when?

Tags: android, android-sensors

I've a problem in understanding one thing. I know that the uses-feature in android is not required in developing application, but i want to prevent some users that haven't a kind of feature, to download my app and give bad votes because "it doesn't work".
Let's give you an example: If i want to use the TYPE_ORIENTATION in my sensor manager, i know that it uses the accelerometer for x and y axis. But in the z axis, if i'm not wrong, it focus the 0 degrees to the magnetic north. So it's using the compass hardware.

My question is: Do i have to insert the android.hardware.compass in the uses-feature? Or the android.hardware.accelerometer is enough? Is there a way to understand what uses-feature i have to put in (in general)?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Have you read this?...http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html

Comment: Yes, i read it. But i can't find my answer. I still don't know for example, if i use TYPE_ORIENTATION if i have to put the compass or not